# .REnviron with special characters

Tags: r

I am having trouble trying to add environment variables to a REnviron file that have special characters. This is on a Debian machine with the file located at `/usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron`. If my value has a `&`, I get a weird error when installing packages (although the package installs fine):

REnviron file: `TEST_KEY=HEY&X&THERE`

Command: `install.packages(futures)`

Error:

```
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rcmd: 468: /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron: THERE: not found
/usr/lib/R/bin/Rcmd: 468: /usr/lib/R/etc/Renviron: X: not found
```

Which seems like it's because `&` is a special character. I can fix this by putting quotes around the value like this: `TEST_KEY="HEY&X&THERE"`. However at that point I can't figure out how to handle when a value itself has a `"` in it. For example if I wanted the value to be `HEY&"&THERE` I am not sure how to format that (a backlash in front of the quote didn't work). I tried `"HEY&\"&THERE"`, but that left the \ in the string once loaded into R. Which leads me to my broader question:

**How can I ensure that anything that satisfies linux environment variable styling rules works in an REnviron file?**

Update: this seems to be a Debian specific issue. You can recreate it using the `debian:bullseye-slim` docker image, installing R, then editing the Renviron to have a `&` in it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce a problem: I inserted that literal key=value in my `.REnviron`, confirmed that it is being used/seed by R, then tried installed a package from CRAN without error. This seems like it's a reduced problem (generally a good thing), is there something different about the real key=value pair you're using, or is this perfectly representative? What key(s) are you setting? Does the value have any other special characters?

Comment: So far I've had it happen with any key that has a "&" in it. This is while running on debian and from RStudio Server.

Comment: Okay. I tested on windows, which could certainly behave differently. **Edit**: I just tested on ubuntu-16/R-4.0.5 as well, no error.

Comment: Update: I just tested with using purely the `debian:bullseye-slim` docker image and that has this same error. It seems like specifically a debian thing.

Comment: As a workaround, you can try using .Rprofile instead of .Renviron: `Sys.setenv(TEST_KEY="HEY&X&THERE")`

Answer (score 1):

Okay I spent an hour looking into this and I think there is the answer.

In both Ubuntu and Debian (and maybe other systems too), the Renviron file gets executed within bash. So what you're typing in the file is exactly bash commands. You can see in lines 39-40 of `RCmd` the commands:

```sh
. "${R_HOME}/etc${R_ARCH}/Renviron"
export `sed 's/^ *#.*//; s/^\([^=]*\)=.*/\1/' "${R_HOME}/etc${R_ARCH}/Renviron"`
```

The first line runs the Renviron file in the shell, the second then exports the variable names based on lines that have a `=` in them.

So in our case the way to handle this is to put double quotations around all the values, and any double-quote within the string should get a `\` before it. The reason why I didn't realize the solution before I posted the question is that I didn't use `cat()` when printing my text in R, which removes the leading `\`. So: `"HEY&\"&THERE"` would be the right way to do it.

To recap:

1. The Renviron file is executed on the shell
2. To handle special characters in strings you use the same logic you would in the OS (so double quotes with `\` to escape actual double quotes).